# $_POST vacio despues de enviar un formulario en servidor

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, formularios, post

Tengo un problema. Antes no me sucedia pero recien subi los nuevos archivos al servidor de mi hosting que es Inmotion Hostong. Con localhost no tengo ningun problema pero al realizar un fomrulrio simple en el servidor, en la pagina a la que me dirige el action, el $_POST me aparee como un array vacio.

Hice un mini formulario como ejemplo.

```
<form action="login-admin.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input name="prueba" value="5"></input>
<button type="submit" name="accion" value="Submit">Obtener valor</button>
 </form>
```

Al momento de enviar el formulario, intento validar que se hayan enviado los datos

```
if(isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] === 'Submit'){
   print_r($_POST);
}else{
  echo "no hay datos";
}
```

Me devuelve

```
no hay datos
```

Como puedo arreglar esto?
He leido que puede ser porque es posible que se reescriba la direccion de action y por lo tanto se resetea el $_POST (no estoy segura de como funciona)
Sin embargo ya probe varias soluciones como agregar un / al final de la dirección del action.

Otra cosa es que revisara el .htaccess, pero solo tengo lo siguiente y no se de que manera afecte.

```
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Ya revise y me las devuelve porque antes del if tambien imprimi el post, lo editare

Comment: En mi caso tu código funciona, devuelve esto: `Array ( [prueba] => 5 [accion] => Submit )` Revisa que el `if(isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] === 'Submit'){` está en el archivo correcto, debería llamarse `login-admin.php` y estar en el mismo directorio que el archivo del `form`. A veces falla por problemas de caché, para descartar, limpia la caché, o prueba en modo incógnito o crea un nuevo archivo para el `action`. Por cierto, si el `form` no envía archivos, no tiene sentido declararlo como `multipart`

Comment: Si sospechas que está ocurriendo una redirección es fácil verificarlo: revisa la URL que hay en la barra del navegador cuando se envía el formulario, si no coincide con `login-admin.php` entonces sí, está habiendo una redirección. Eso no ocurre en el trozo de `.htaccess` que muestras.

Answer (score 0):

En el post tiene que ser el nombre del input (name="prueba") no del value del boton

```
if($_POST['prueba']){
   $input1 = $_POST['prueba'];
   echo "$input1";
}else{
   echo "no hay datos";
}
```